# Stream an FLVPlayback through the internet

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, flvplayback

I have a video in flash in the size of 19 MB (5 minutes) and I want the user to see what that has been loaded so far, or even get an indication of what has been loaded - so he won't be stuck in a blank screen until the video loads.

The quality of the video is important so I won't resize it - but how can I:

1. stream it so the user can see what that has been loaded so far
2. give him an indication of how long he will need to wait until it loads.

My code looks something like this:

```
import fl.video.*;

var video = new FLVPlayback();
video.fullScreenTakeOver = false;
video.source = "MansfredLoop.f4v";
stage.addChild(video);
```

Where do I start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import fl.video.*;

var totalBytes:int;

var loadedBytes:int;

var remainingBytes:int;

var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(100);

var video = new FLVPlayback();
video.fullScreenTakeOver = false;
video.source = "MansfredLoop.f4v";
stage.addChild(video);

myTimer.addEventListener("timer", timerHandler);
myTimer.start();

totalBytes = video.bytesLoaded;

function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void {

    loadedBytes = video.bytesLoaded;
    remainingBytes = totalBytes - loadedBytes;
}
```